# Using GLM .obj loader in an Objective-C program

Tags: objective-c, opengl, .obj

I am trying to use GLM to load a .obj object in my Objective-C Program (Xcode 4.4 Mac Os X). I have added the glm folder to my project. i try to import it using #import "glm/glm.hpp", but the program doesn't build. some of the errors are the following: (this errors are produced in the GLM files)

```
namespace glm{         //Unknown type name 'namespace'
namespace detail
{ .....
```

It doesn't find the cstdlib, cmath, and other libraries.

This happens because my program is in Objective-c and the GLM doesn't work with this language?

Comment: I think you're slightly confused. There are two libraries named GLM: 1) [OpenGL Mathematics](http://glm.g-truc.net/), and 2) [GLM: Wavefront OBJ file loader](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/). #1 does not do any .obj loading

Answer (score 1):

Those are all symptoms of trying to compile a C++ application with a C compiler.  Namespace is a C++ keyword, and cstdlib, cmath, etc. are C++ names for standard C headers.  You'll have to migrate your project to Objective-C++ to be able to use GLM.

Comment: Don't forget to rename any .m files to .mm as part of the process. Often Xcode is stubborn about this extension being correct.

Answer (score 1):

Any files that uses the GLM library will require that file extensions to be renamed to .mm as it uses Objective-C++.  Also, as it is only a file, and not a framework, you only need to put `#import "glm.hpp"`